# In the EU, how much protection do I have if I report an assault on myself by my department head?

Tags: interpersonal-issues, legal-issues, europe

I had a very ugly incident at my corrupt institute (I live in E. EU). In short, I was assaulted by one of the department's heads during my own group meeting on my own grant for daring to "back talk" after he had abusively terminated that meeting. Him, and my own department's head had sabotaged my projects by sidetracking the people working on them, threatening them, and, lately, by denying access to shared research facilities which they don't really use.

As this behavior has been tolerated by the director (who is the ultimate god there), I expect things only to get worse. I'm seriously considering whistleblowing as my only option, as my reports of the incidents are merely CYA actions since they've gone unnoticed so far.

I might be out on my ass by next week for the "lese-majeste" of this week. If I do whistleblow, is there a way within EU to protect myself and my research group? I doubt I'll get any understanding in my own country.

Update: I'm not fired, they just found a nice and sneaky way to dissolve my research group. Funnily enough, no one is on my side, including the people who witnessed the incident.

Comment: Verbally assaulted or physically assaulted?

Comment: @Buffy Both, and in front of my colleagues who work on my project. Not that any of them would have the guts to go in court against that guy.

Comment: Physical assault is a police matter. But do you see any future for yourself in this situation? It doesn't look like it has any possible happy ending. Not unless there are regular procedure for removing bad actors. Those are pretty rare most places.

Comment: In my country, physical assault without a weapon or blood isn't a police matter, and verbal assault is how most people here speak. In any case, I haven't been assaulted since high school, so I didn't call the police because I didn't think about it at that time.

Comment: If you are going this route, I think you need to talk to a lawyer. This seems like too delicate a situation to rely on the advice of random Internet strangers.

Comment: I don't want to do it, because I lose almost 30 years of hard work if they kick me out, and that is inevitable if I go over their heads and whistleblow. I want them to just remove him, and leave me alone with my circles.

Comment: @Magicsowon You know how the thing with the circles ended. Get yourself a mercenary, i.e. a lawyer and consult, they will have seen many cases and know best what your options are. I assume leaving that place is not an option?

Comment: It is not clear who you would be whistle blowing to and about what if assault without a weapon or blood is not a police matter, it is not clear that the head did anything legally wrong.

Comment: I'm tied in my grants and a few promising collaborations, and it looked like I was forming a functional research group, after failing my first  attempt due to my people leaving over what is there. I can't leave town because of family ties. I can definitely leave the place, but I think it's a really stupid end for my career.

Comment: @StrongBad At least, you put in perspective. When I was in US, one of my colleagues did a similar thing, and the police showed up in five minutes. After a short discussion about "pressing charges" things got very calm around there.

Comment: The higher the stakes, the more important it is to do it right. With 30 years of hard work on the line, I'd engage a lawyer. The cost of botching it up is just too high.

Comment: I see no whistle to blow here. Also, your question is no clear: you refuse any suggested solutions as it is not how is done in your country.

Comment: You don't say where this took place, but in response to suggestions to inform the police that you've been assaulted, you say that in your country physical assault is not a police matter.  If that is true, then how can you possibly get reasonable help from people who know so little about your situation that the most basic tenets of their society don't apply to you?

Comment: Given your update, it sounds like there is an atmosphere of fear. Maybe it is time to take advantage of the EU's open borders.

Comment: To the close voter, verbal assault and physical assault are different issues. We are Academia. This means we have received high education and civilized. Closing this question means we keep quiet on violence.

Answer (score 4):

If the matter has escalated to a physical assault then you have the option to contact the police.  For lesser issues concerning corruption or maladministration of public resources, you should consider searching for the closest equivalent of an ombudsman for your university sector.  In public industries with an ombudsman it is usual to be able to make a report of maladministration or corruption, and there are protections for whistle-blowers who file reports on these matters.  Specific rules vary according to the laws of the country and the specific industry ombudsman, so you should first check to find the appropriate ombudsman and check the protections for whistle-blowers that apply in your case.  If you have a lot invested it is probably also a good idea to speak to a lawyer to get advice on the available reporting mechanisms and legal protections.